# Merging queries to return ways/nodes that are within relations matching criteria using Overpass API

Tags: area, query, overpass-api, overpass-turbo, relation

**Motivation** - I am currently processing a number of relations matching criteria and then doing an additional query to get all the ways/nodes within those relations. .

**Goal** - I'm trying to simplify this and do a single query that can return matching nodes/ways across more than one relation in a single query.

The first query gets all the relations for a given bounding box

```
    [out:json][timeout:900];
    relation({{bbox}});map_to_area->.some_area;
    (
      relation[capital](area.some_area);
      relation[place~"city|town|village|hamlet"](area.some_area);
      relation[admin_level~"8"](area.some_area);
    );
    out body;
    >;
    out skel qt;
```

The next query uses the ids returned in the previous query and loops through each one to get the ways.

````
    [out:json];
    relation(each_relation_id_from_previous_query);map_to_area->.a;
    (
    way(area.a)
    ['name']
    ['highway']
    ['highway' !~ 'path']
    ['highway' !~ 'steps']
    ['highway' !~ 'motorway']
    ['highway' !~ 'motorway_link']
    ['highway' !~ 'raceway']
    ['highway' !~ 'bridleway']
    ['highway' !~ 'proposed']
    ['highway' !~ 'construction']
    ['highway' !~ 'elevator']
    ['highway' !~ 'bus_guideway']
    ['highway' !~ 'bus_stop']
    ['highway' !~ 'footway']
    ['highway' !~ 'cycleway']
    ['highway' !~ 'trunk']
    ['service' !~ 'driveway']
    ['foot' !~ 'no']
    ['access' !~ 'private']
    ['access' !~ 'no'];
    );
    (._;>;);
    out;
    ```

I'm wondering if it's possible to combine these so I can query an area (let's say {{bbox}}) and only return ways/nodes that fall within the criteria for relations in the first query.
````